# How to count a group of 7 such that the first three are female and the final 4 are male?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am quite stuck on how to turn this into a counting problem. The question is, "Twenty mice, ten males and ten females live in a house. The resident cat, Tom, is bored and decides to capture 7 of the mice. You may assume that Tom is equally likely to encounter any of the remaining mice at any point. What is the chance that the first 3 mice he captures are female and the last 4 are male?" Since this is sampling without replacement, this could be solved by multiplying the probability of drawing each individual mouse.

I understand how to approach the problem using probability. I am curious how one would figure this out using counting rather than using probabilities.

I tried to first count the total number of ways to draw 7 mice, which would be `10 nCr 7`. I cannot quite figure out how to count the number of ways we could first pick 3 female mice and pick the last 4 as male mice. I thought it would be something like `10 nCr 3 * 10 nCr 4`, but I don't get the correct answer when I try to calculate the probability doing that. How would I go about counting the number of ways to draw the first 3 as females and the last 4 as males?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction. However, I think using permutations instead of combinations when counting in this problem is more straightforward.

We know that there are $20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14$ ways of filling in the first 3 and then the last 4 positions with the 20 mice (assuming order matters).
Among these permutations, $(10\cdot9\cdot8)\cdot(10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7)$ of them satisfy the condition that the first 3 are female and the last 4 are male.

Therefore, the probability is:
$$\frac{(10\cdot9\cdot8)\cdot(10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7)}{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14} = \boxed{\frac{3}{323}}$$

Notice that when you use permutations, the final probability equation you arrive at is exactly the same as if you multiply the probabilities of drawing each individual mouse.